# JSON failed to write genesis block: invalid character '\\' looking for beginning of object key string

Tags: json, go, blockchain, truffle

I am trying to build up the genesis, and I have encountered many errors while doing so.After I inputed geth `init genesis.json` on the terminal of the same directory, but I got this:

```
Caros-MacBook-Pro:testcmy caro$ geth init genesis.json
I0223 18:52:32.817358 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /Users/caro/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata
I0223 18:52:32.976868 ethdb/database.go:176] closed db:/Users/caro/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata
I0223 18:52:32.976933 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /Users/caro/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata
Fatal: failed to write genesis block: invalid character '\\' looking for beginning of object key string
```

I referred to this website: http://hypernephelist.com/2016/05/30/deploying-a-private-Ethereum-blockchain.html  and I followed the steps.

the .json is as follows:

```
{
    "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",

"mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "difficulty": "0x4000",

 "alloc": {},

"coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",

"timestamp": "0x00",

 "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",

 "extraData": "Custom Ethereum Genesis Block",

 "gasLimit": "0xffffffff"
}
```

So, where is the mysterious invalid \? There is no \ in the json! What's wrong with it?

Comment: I would check your assumptions. I was able to init with the above json just fine. Are you sure you are actually running init against the above json?

Comment: I am pretty sure about that~and I am so confused about the result

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're using a text editor that adds some extra characters. Try using nano or anything similar

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [Answering Questions Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you